# Scroll view in Kivy is not scrolling, How could a fix this?

Tags: python, class, kivy, scrollview, kivy-language

I want to be able to scroll within the buttons numbered 10-1 but it wont let me scroll. Any solutions? I was finally able to put the buttons in a scrollview but after all my effort I am not able to move it. It just crams into the space provided and doesn't move at all.

[image: :]

```
    orientation: "vertical"
    SongText:
        size_hint: 1,0.35
    PausePlay:
        size_hint: 1,0.1
    ScrollView:
        orientation: "vertical"
        PlayList:
            orientation: "vertical"
    AddDeleteShuffle:
        size_hint: 1,0.2

<SongText>:
    Label:
        id: songtitle
        text: "Song Title"
<PausePlay>:
    Button:
        id: play
        text: "Play"
    Button:
        id: pause
        text: "Pause"
```

This is the main area of focus I think nothing is needed here but who knows.

```
<PlayList>:   #Main area of conceren

<AddDeleteShuffle>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Shuffle"
        Button:
            text: "Delete"
        Button:
            text: "Shuffle"
```

```
kv file ^

py file
```

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class AddDeleteShuffle(BoxLayout):
    pass
```

```
class PlayList(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(0,10):
            size = dp(100)
            b = Button(text=str(i+1), size_hint=(1,None), size=(size,size))
            self.add_widget(b)
```

Class for the playlist it is inside a scroll view, but I can't move it. Maybe I have to add a layout in the kv file. I have no idea.

```
class PausePlay(BoxLayout):
    pass

class SongText(BoxLayout):
    pass

class AppLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Sound5App(App):
    def build(self):
        return AppLayout()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    Sound5App().run()
```

Comment: Try adding ```size_hint_y:None``` to the ScrollView

Comment: I did I think, no luck @Ctrl7

Comment: Try adding the ```size_hint_y:None```along with ```height:self.minimum_height``` in your BoxLayout

Comment: Thank you @Ctrl7 but I already solved it :)